# use php preg_replace to replace alt="20x20" with style="width:20;height:20;"

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

How would I use php `preg_replace` to parse a string of HTML and replace

`alt="20x20"` with `style="width:20;height:20;"`

Any help is appreciated.

I tried this.

```
$pattern = '/(<img.*) alt="(\d+)x(\d+)"(.*style=")(.*)$/';
$style = '$1$4width:$2px;height:$3px;$5';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, $style, $text);
```

Comment: Simple. You don't. You use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) to manipulate the html.

Comment: If you *did* happen manipulate html with `preg_replace` you'd likely try first.

Comment: I would prefer a php solution, but can you provide an example of the javascript or jquery

Comment: Could you show example input?

Comment: an example of the preg_replace to use?

Comment: People here don't code for free (well, some might unfortunately); try something. If it doesn't work then ask a question — that's the general rule.

Comment: I posted an answer just now but I have delete it after reading @ILI's comment above. He's got a point. Try something first and we'll help you from there.

Comment: your right, sorry for presuming otherwise.

Comment: ok, I edited to add what I tried, again sorry for the presumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need preg_replace to do this. You can use [str_replace](https://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$html = '<img alt="20x20" />';

preg_match('/<img.*?alt="(.*?)".*>/',$html,$match);

$search = 'alt="' . $match[1] . '"';

list($width, $height) = explode('x', $match[1]);

if(is_numeric($width) && is_numeric($height))
{
    $replace = 'style="width:' . $width . 'px;height:' . $height . 'px;"';
    echo str_replace($search, $replace, $html);
}
```

Output:

> ```
> <img style="width:20px;height:20px;">
> ```

Comment: The alt tag could change each time. I just suck at regex

Comment: Oh, so you are looking for anything within the alt tag with #x# then?

Comment: @Russ if this is the preferred answer then you should accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using regular expressions to alter HTML markup you'll no doubt get stuck sometime, at which point you'd do well to look into something like Python's beautiful soup, or possibly the goode olde tidy library, which I think comes included as part of the PHP spec. But for now:

```
  <?php
      $originalString = 'Your string containing <img src="xyz.png" alt="20x20">';
      $patternToFind = '/alt="20x20"/i';
      $replacementString = 'style="width:20;height:20;"';
      preg_replace($patternToFind, $replacementString, $originalString);
 ?>
```

And since it seems a lot of people are mighty peeved at what seems to be a code request, you might check this link out for php.net's guidance. It's not always this clear in explaining PHP's constructs, but would have solved your problem easily in this case:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments you should use DOM to manipulate HTML codes.
If you want to do this by preg_replace anyway, I'd suggest to find out the regex by yourself with the help of sites like [this one](http://www.regexr.com/).